# Possible Solutions to First-Order Linear Homogeneous Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the functions $y_1(x) = e^x$ and $y_2(x) = e^{-x}$. Can both functions be solutions of the same first-order linear homogeneous equation?

I thought that the answer was yes, but I could not find an example. Can someone explain to me why this would not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y_1(x) = e^x$ and $y_2(x) = e^{-x}$ are independent functions so they could not be both the solutions of the same first-order linear homogeneous equation!